# How to identify the columns with more than 20 unique values in pandas for all columns

Tags: python, pandas

Need to segregate only the columns with more than 20 unique values for all the columns in pandas_python (this is a solution for that): if anything else better, please comment:

```
enter code here
col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat=[]
for col in data.columns:
    if data[col].dtype =='O':
        if len(data[col].unique()) >20:
            col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat.append(data[col].name)
        else:
            continue

print(col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat)
print('total number of columns with more than 20 number of unique value is',len(col_with_morethan_20_unique_values_cat))



 # The o/p will be as:
['CONTRACT NO', 'X2','X3',,,,,,,..]
total number of columns with more than 20 number of unique value is 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same can be obtained now by, having list comprehension and giving two conditions 
1). If the column have the dtype as "O" - object/category
2). and also if the unique values or more than any counts ( here it is 20 ).
Same result is achieved as similar to the previous one.

```
cols_more_than_20 = [col for col in data.columns if data[col].dtype =='O' and data[col].nunique()  > 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cols_more_than_20 = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].nunique() > 20]
```

Comment: Thanks @nag for the response, now i added one more condition in if statement to have exact replica result of my previous code. ie, edited the code to check condition for checking dtype of column and let proceed only if it is categorical ( non numeric )